# How to delegate DNS for a subdomain to my own BIND9 server?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I have a VPS (running Debian) and a domain ("mydomain.net"). What I want to achieve is this: I want to create a subdomain "home.mydomain.net" for dynamic hosts in my home, e.g. my NAS etc., so that I can resolve my NAS from everywhere with "nas.home.mydomain.net". (In the end I want to build my own DynDNS service, but the update part etc. is not the point here, I can handle that.)

Let's assume that I want to have a DNS entry for `test.home.mydomain.net` that points to `8.8.8.8` for now (as I can be sure that there will be an ICMP echo, I can change that later).

From what I read while researching how to configure things, I think I need to have these things:

- a BIND9 DNS server running on my VPS
- an `A` record in `mydomain.net`'s DNS zone pointing to my own DNS server
- an `NS` record in `mydomain.net`'s DNS zone that delegates requests for `home.mydomain.net` to the aforementioned nameserver on my VPS

In my VPS administration backend I can edit the DNS zone for my `mydomain.net` and I added the entries mentioned above, these are the entries now (123.123.123.123 stands for the fixed IPv4 address of my VPS):

```
mydomain.net        86400   SOA 0   ns1.myprovider.net. hostmaster.myprovider.net. 2018041707 3600 1200 2419200 86400   
mydomain.net        86400   NS  0   ns1.myprovider.net  
mydomain.net        86400   NS  0   ns2.myprovider.net  
mydomain.net        86400   NS  0   ns3.myprovider.net  
home.mydomain.net   86400   NS  0   ns.mydomain.net 
ns.mydomain.net     86400   A   0   123.123.123.123
mydomain.net        86400   A   0   123.123.123.123
www.mydomain.net    86400   A   0   123.123.123.123
```

Is this correct so far? At this point I can successfully ping `ns.mydomain.net`.

When I do an `nslookup www.mydomain.net` from a separate Windows box, it gets resolved correctly to 123.123.123.123.

When I try to lookup something not existing like `nslookup xyz.mydomain.net`, I get an instant answer that the domain is not existing.

When I try to resolve e.g. `test.home.mydomain.net`, it takes some seconds until I get `DNS request timed out.`. From what I understand, this is correct so far, is it? The DNS request gets delegated to `ns.mydomain.net`, but there's nothing answering yet, so I get a timeout.

Next step: installing and configuring BIND9 on my Debian VPS. I freshly installed it (`apt install bind9`). Now I want to set it up in such a way that it only takes care of resolving hosts in `home.mydomain.net`. I don't need a full-grown DNS server that forwards for arbitrary requests etc., all I need is that it "feels responsible" for hosts in `home.mydomain.net` and (for now) resolves `test.home.mydomain.net` to 8.8.8.8. There's an overwhelming amount of information on bind9 configuration, but I did not manage to find out what exactly I need to do. Here's what I tried:

***(Updated)***
This is my `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
zone "home.mydomain.net" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.home.mydomain.net";
};
```

And this is the corresponding `/etc/bind/db.home.mydomain.net`:

```
$TTL 5
@ IN SOA ns.mydomain.net. root.mydomain.net. (
    10;
    3600;
    1200;
    2419200;
    86400;
);
ns.mydomain.net  IN      A    [My NS IPv4 address]
ns.mydomain.net  IN      AAAA [My NS IPv6 address]
test             IN      A    8.8.8.8
```

This does not work after restarting bind9, I can't resolve `test.home.mydomain.net`to 8.8.8.8., I'm still running into a request timeout. I think I might not have completely understood the role of the SOA record, otherwise I missed something else. Can anybody tell me what's missing and/or wrong?

***Update:***

The above configuration works now - after adding A and/or AAAA records for my nameserver. It feels a bit strange that you have to give these records as they point to *itself*? Why is that?

Comment: While I am not 100% sure, the trailing dot in zone name in zone statement may be an issue here. Are there any messages in the logs? Is there /etc/bind/named.conf file which includes /etc/bind/named.conf.local file? Do you have a firewall on your VPS? If yes - are TCP and UDP ports 53 open?

Comment: You're right, the dot in the zone name was wrong. Besides that, I got it working and I updated the question with my current config. I still wonder why I have to add A/AAAA records for the nameserver itself?